# Cannot Get the Bin Location Counts, Is giving me the count of how many of the item there is

Tags: excel

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15975,SMALL(IF($F$3=$A$2:$A$15975,ROW($A$2:$A$15975)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$15975))+1,""),ROW(A1))),"")`

I am trying to get the bin locations for the part number which would be in Cell F3, the bins are in column B, but it is giving me the counts in column A. Below is how my sheet looks in Excel:

```
Item          Bin            Qty on Hand            Description
00805Z4     E&ONOK810             140              LENS(TOUCH/LCD):NOK810
00809P2     VN3-313-013-05        440              FLEX(RIB),TOUCH:NOK521
0089V99     Rclm Instransit       1                NOK710-LENS(TOUCH)
0089V99     E&ONOK710             1                NOK710-LENS(TOUCH)
0089V99     Rclm Instransit       6                NOK710-LENS(TOUCH)
0089V99-U   E&ONOK710             389              NOK710-LENS(TOUCH)
0089V99-U   a2                    17               NOK710-LENS(TOUCH)
0089W00     E4B                   1                LENS(TOUCH)
0089W00-U   vn3-313-024-50        1                NOK710-LENS(TOUCH)
0089W00-U   VN3-313-023-50        159              NOK710-LENS(TOUCH)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11;SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$11=$F$3;ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1;"");ROWS($A$2:A2)))
```

Depending on your settings you may need to replace ";" by "," for field separators

This is an array formula so don't forget to Ctrl Shift Enter in the end.
The first time you write the formula you get the first BIN, as you copy down you get all the others

Comment: when putting the code do you mean the , or the ; in your formula

Comment: I dont have any","...I mean replace my ";" (semicolon) by "," (colon)